# photo album for Mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have to make a photo album for my mobile app.I am getting the images for photo album from local database using ajax call.I have used many of 'jquery mobile' plugin for it.but any one is not working.
        so any one have good example and solution for it, please suggest me. 
Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the real advantage of using Ajax in a mobile photo-album?

Anyway I found some photogalleries (one or 2 not based on jquery-mobile):

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/27/awesome-mobile-image-gallery-web-app/

http://neteye.github.com/touch-gallery.html

http://www.photoswipe.com/

http://www.digicrafts.com.hk/components/JSMobilePhotoAlbum

Alternatively you can:
1. create the albums as list items.
2. in album view show thumbnails of photos
3. Click on thumbnail = show photo in fullscreen with a back button.

Good luck :)